# Bootstrap 4 pill tabs won't load content -- Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to load partials in 3 separate tabs with bootstrap 4 tab/pill navigation. The tabs themselves are not activating, the default is only being used. Lastly, is it possible to AJAX refresh the partial when the button is clicked?

```
 <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item pill-1">
          <a class="nav-link active bttn-simple bttn-md" id="pills-movies-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-movies" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-movies" aria-selected="true">Popular Movies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pill-2">
          <a class="nav-link bttn-simple bttn-md" id="pills-photo-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-photos" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-photos" aria-selected="false">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pill-3">
          <a class="nav-link bttn-simple bttn-md" id="pills-feature-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-features" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-features" aria-selected="false">Features</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-movies" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-movie-tab">
                <%= render @movies %>
              <%= paginate @movies %>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-photos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-photo-tab">
              <%= render @photos %>
              <%= paginate @photos %>
              <p>Hi Tab 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-features" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-feature-tab">
              <%= render @features %>
              <%= paginate @features %>
              <p>Hi Tab 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

UPDATE:
I added the click event that should activate the tabs below

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
        $('#myTab a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $(this).tab('show')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send request via AJAX to your controller and then replace html data in this tab.

Something like this:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $.ajax({
      data: { type: type },
      url: window.location.pathname,
      success: function(data){
        $("#" + type).html(data.html);
      }
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { ... }
    format.json { 
      type = params[:type]
      records = type.camelize.constantize.all

      render json: { 
        html: render_to_string(partial: "#{type.pluralize}",
                               layout: false,
                               formats: [:html],
                               locals: { records: records })
      }
     }                                                    
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this the only approach to loading partials for the bootstrap 4 tabs? The default is HTML only??

Comment: It only seems to work with the tab-pane as a default. I'll just stylize it and keep moving forward. Thanks.

Comment: You can load all data when user opens page -> just switch between tabs (all partials already rendered at this moment)

Or you can load data for specific tab via AJAX each time when user switches them. 

Maybe I do not quite understand your question.
Do you mean that tab not show on when you clicking on it? Or tab is showing on without any rendered data?

Comment: What I'm doing is loading the partials on tab button press. I don't know which is more efficient. Load all when the page renders or load using AJAX button clicks.